# Asynctask error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have a Fragment which contains a AsyncTask :

```
class GetPharmacieDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Chargement. Patienter ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", pid));
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);



                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    txtRegion.setText(product.getString(TAG_REGION));

                    txtAddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                    lati = product.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    longi = product.getString(TAG_LANGITUDE);
                }else{
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            if(pDialog != null){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
```

when i open the fragment for the first time its run good but when i navigate to another Fragment and i return another time to the first fragment it's crashed
Log cat:

```
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4746)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:854)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4075)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10386)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10341)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6439)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3696)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3554)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3529)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at com.example.fitness2.InformationsSwipe$GetPharmacieDetails.doInBackground(InformationsSwipe.java:145)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at com.example.fitness2.InformationsSwipe$GetPharmacieDetails.doInBackground(InformationsSwipe.java:1)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-16 00:30:42.038: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     ... 4 more
02-16 00:30:42.070: W/EGL_emulation(2391): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-16 00:30:42.158: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(2391): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

i think the problem was here:

```
txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
txtRegion.setText(product.getString(TAG_REGION));
txtAddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
lati = product.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
longi = product.getString(TAG_LANGITUDE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the UI Thread (Main Thread) from another Thread, It cause lot of errors internally, try making the `product` variable as local and later in `onPostExecute` set the text to the `TextViews`

```
class GetPharmacieDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    private JSONObject product;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Chargement. Patienter ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", pid));
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            // Note that product details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_product_detials, "GET", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully received product details
                JSONArray productObj = json
                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                // get first product object from JSON Array
                product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
            }else{
                // product with pid not found
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        if(null!=product){
            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                txtRegion.setText(product.getString(TAG_REGION));
                txtAddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
                lati = product.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                longi = product.getString(TAG_LANGITUDE);
        }
        if(pDialog != null){
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the UI inside doInBackground(). That method runs on a background thread that is not synchronised with the GUI thread, hence a CalledFromWrongThreadException results.

One option is to schedule the UI updates on the GUI thread using the runOnUiThread() method. Note that this method belongs to Activity, so you'll need to use it via a reference to the fragment's parent:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
        txtRegion.setText(product.getString(TAG_REGION));
        txtAddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
    }
});
```

However the correct way to use AsyncTask is to perform any UI updates in onPostExecute(), which is synchronised with the GUI thread. To do it this way, change the 3rd parameter in the AsyncTask definition to JSONObject (this is the type you will return from doInBackground that is then passed into onPostExecute):

```
class GetPharmacieDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
```

Change doInBackground to return a JSONObject:

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
```

...and no longer update the UI within doInBackground. Instead, return the reference to 'product':

```
...
if (success == 1) {
    JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);
    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

    //txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
    //txtRegion.setText(product.getString(TAG_REGION));
    //txtAddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));

    lati = product.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
    longi = product.getString(TAG_LANGITUDE);
    return product;
}else{
...
```

Change onPostExecute to receive the JSONObject and update the UI here, as long as the reference provided from doInBackground is not null:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject product) {
    if (product != null) {
        txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
        txtRegion.setText(product.getString(TAG_REGION));
        txtAddress.setText(product.getString(TAG_ADDRESS));
    }

    // dismiss the dialog once got all details
    if(pDialog != null){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```